# How to reassign the nested array keys based on Angular Reactive Forms?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-forms

I am working to recreate the nested array for Angular Reactive Forms.

**Existing Nested Array.**

```
nestedArray = [{
    id:'abc',
    required:true,
    children:[{
        id:"bcd",
        parentId:"abc",
        required:true,
        children:[{
            id:"cde",
            parentId:"bcd",
            required:false,
            children:[{
                id:"def",
                parentId:"cde",
                required:true,
                children:[{
                    id:"efg",
                    parentId:"def",
                    required:false,                        
                }]
            },
            {
                id: "xyz",
                parentId: "cde",
                required: true,
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Recreate this array for **Angular Reactive Forms**

```
nestedArray= this.fb.group({
    abc: [''],
    bcd: this.fb.group({
      cde: [''],
      efg: [''],
    }),
  });
```

Above array is incorrect, looking for the right way to create the children in Angular Reactive Form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make a recursive function that return a FormControl or a FormGroup

```
  form = new FormArray(this.nestedArray.map(x=>{
    const group=new FormGroup({})
    group.addControl(x.id,this.getGroup(x))
    return group
    }));

  getGroup(data: any) {
    if (!data.children)
      return new FormControl()
    const group = new FormGroup({});
    if (data.children) {
      
      data.children.forEach(x=>{
        group.addControl(x.id,this.getGroup(x))
      })
    }
    return group;
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6mfncj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** really the answer is wrong, becaouse we has no form control to the "parents". the function must be like

```
  form = new FormArray(this.nestedArray.map(x=>this.getGroup(x)))
  getGroup(data: any) {
    if (!data.children)
    { 
      return new FormControl)
    }
    const group = new FormGroup({});
    group.addControl(data.id,new FormControl())
    if (data.children) {
      
      data.children.forEach(x=>{
        group.addControl(x.id,this.getGroup(x))
      })
    }
    return group;
  }
```

Well, the question is how conrol this crazy form. We can try create a "recursive template", but I think it's better another aproach. Imagine you has an array of elements, each one with three porperties: "index","label" and "control". And control is a reference to the FormControl of our form. Then we can construct an .html like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of controls">
    <span [style.margin-left]="item.index*10+'px'">{{item.label}}</span>
    <input [formControl]="item.control">
    <span *ngIf="item.control.errors?.required">*</span>
</div>
```

easy no? just use directly `[formControl]` and `item.control.errors` or `item.control.touched`

Well, for this first declare an empty array

```
  controls:any[]=[];
```

And change the fuction so we add the group in two steps: 1.-create the formControl, 2.-Add to the group, the third step is add to our array an object with {label,control and "index"}. Well it's typical when we has a recursive function to want know the "index" of the recursion.

```
  //we pass as index 0 at first
  form = new FormArray(this.nestedArray.map(x=>this.getGroup(x,0)))
  getGroup(data: any,index:number) {
    if (!data.children)
    { 
      //create the control
      const control=new FormControl('',data.required?Validators.required:null)

      //add to the array this.controls
      this.controls.push({control:control,label:data.id,index:index})

      //return control
      return control
    }
    const group = new FormGroup({});
    index++
    //create the control
    const control=new FormControl('',data.required?Validators.required:null)

    //add to the array this.controls
    this.controls.push({control:control,label:data.id,index:index})

    //add the control to the group
    group.addControl(data.id,control)

    if (data.children) {
      data.children.forEach(x=>{
        group.addControl(x.id,this.getGroup(x,index++))
      })
    }
    return group;
  }
```

Well, In the stackblitz add the property "value" to our complex object, to show how can do it, and we use as "label" the "id" -perhafs our complex object need a new property label-

Comment: How can we add the validation `group.addControl(x.id,this.getGroup(x))` 
 `Validators.required`

Comment: Any suggestion to print these controls on HTML template?

Comment: @Amit, I updated the answer. Really I re-make all the answer because the first attemp was wrong

Answer (score 0):

just a pseudo code below, but you will need to iterate and create the final key-value object to get similar structure...

anyhow there are some tools solving similar issues, consider this: https://jsonforms.io/ - i'd consider those first.

```
function patch (array: any[]): any { 
  let res: any = {};    
  for (let a of array) {
      res[a.id] = a;
      if (a.children && a.children.length) res[a.id]['children'] = patch(a.children)
  }

  return res;    
}
```